# Intuitively, why is $\langle V \lvert W\rangle$ "square" of norm $ \lvert V\rvert$ and not $\lambda \cdot \lvert V\rvert$?

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products, quantum-mechanics

I wanted to gain an intuitive proof of the Schwarz Inequality and Triangle inequality (primer for Quantum Mechanics).
I intuitively interpreted inner product, $\langle V \lvert W\rangle$, as the measure of *likeness*, as "How much $\lvert W\rangle$ is *like* $\lvert V\rangle$ ?". The norm comes to play when I think of, $\langle \frac{V}{\lvert V\rvert}\lvert W\rangle$, as if "*a single tulip is less alike to a field of tupil, than what a bouquet of tupil will be*" (say  if, $\lvert V\rangle$ is a bouquet and $\frac{\lvert V\rangle}{\lvert V\rvert}$ is a single flower).
I am comfortable with this concept of scalar measure as long as comparing distinct objects or generalised vectors. But my intuition breaks down as I think "*how much a bouquet of rose is alike to a bouquet of rose*"; and the intuitive answer seems to be $\lvert rose bouquet\rvert$ and not its square.
 I'm not sure if pursuing such intuitive reasoning will do much good with my course ahead,
but still, what am I missing here?

Comment: How about getting your intuition from vector geometry: $\left< V\mid W\right>$ is like the dot product $V\cdot W$ of vectors $V$ and $W$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng vector geometry drastically limits what a linear vector space can represent. A better way to such approach is coefficient expansion under a basis. But I want to treat a vector as a generalised object and make out the proof. Intuitive all through.

Comment: Does saying "well, every rose in the first bouquet is like every rose in the second bouquet, so there's bouquet squared likenesses" play nice with your intuition?